# Можно ли использовать функцию без декораторов в дальнейшем коде?

Tags: python-3.x

Ребят подскажите есть ли способ использовать повторно функцию обернутую в декораторы,но уже без них в одном модуле??

```
def decor(schet):

    def vlog(a,b):

        print("Выполняем декоратор")
        schet("ki","rill")

    return vlog

def decor2(schet):

    def vlog2(a,b):
        print(a+b)
        print("выполняем 2 декоратор")
        schet("mi","la")

    return vlog2

@decor
@decor2
def schet(a,b):

    print (a+b)
    return a+b

c=schet("sa","sha")

print(c("sa","sha"))
```

Comment: Можно. Просто уберите в следующей функции `@decor
@decor2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Декоратор, это функция, которая сожержит и возвращает замыкание.

[Замыкание](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-python_details_03/#N101CE) - это процедура вместе с привязанной к ней совокупностью данных, которая наследует переменные из их окружения. 
Когда вы передаете обратный вызов функции в качестве аргумента другой функции, 
которая будет выполнять ввод / вывод, эта функция обратного вызова будет вызываться позже, 
и эта функция почти волшебным образом запомнит контекст, в котором она была объявлена, вместе со всеми доступными переменными в этом контексте.
Если функция не использует свободные переменные, она не образует замыкания.

Атрибуты функции [`func_closure`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/) в python `<3.X` или `__closure__` в `>3.X` сохраняют свободные переменные.
Каждая функция в python имеет эти атрибуты, но она не сохраняет никакого содержимого, если свободных переменных нет.
Атрибут `__closure__` возвращает кортеж объектов ячейки, который содержит детали переменных, определенных в охватывающей области.

[взято тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/why-arent-python-nested-functions-called-closures)

Давайте найдем вашу функцию без декоратора:

```
# "задекорированная" функция
print(schet)
#<function decor.<locals>.vlog at 0x032B6348>

# замыкание
print(schet.__closure__)
# (<cell at 0x0308A150: function object at 0x03086300>,)
# посмотри что там
f= schet.__closure__[0].cell_contents
print(f)
# <function decor2.<locals>.vlog2 at 0x03086300>

# вот и оригинальная, "незадекорированная" функция
original_func = f.__closure__[0].cell_contents
print(original_func)
# <function schet at 0x030862B8>
```

Еще один изврат способ, использовать декоратор с параметром, который
будет решать вызывать декорированную, или оригинальную func, например через kwargs ключ, который мы удалим в декораторе, чтобы не передавать его дальше.

```
def decor(schet):
    def vlog(a,b):
        print("Выполняем декоратор")
        schet("ki","rill")
    return vlog

def decor2(schet):
    def vlog2(a,b):
        print(a+b)
        print("выполняем 2 декоратор")
        schet("mi","la")
    return vlog2

def multi_decor(*decors):
    '''декорация, другими декораторами из *decors'''
    def mdecor(func):
        decor_func = original_func = func
        for dec in decors:  # декорация
            decor_func = dec(decor_func)

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if kwargs.pop('multi_decor', True):
                return decor_func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:  # оригинальная или декорированная
                return original_func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper
    return mdecor

@multi_decor(decor, decor2)
def schet(a,b):
    print (a+b)
    return a+b

decor_out = schet("sa","sha")  # декорированная
original_out = schet("sa","sha", multi_decor=False)  # оригинальная
```

Answer (score 2):

Это извращение, конечно. Если такая задача возникает на практике, то, скорее всего, следует пересмотреть структуру кода.

Но, теоретически, можно внутри самого внутреннего декоратора сохранять исходную функцию в какую-то переменную:

```
unwrapped = None


def decor(schet):

    def vlog(a,b):

        print("Выполняем декоратор")
        schet("ki","rill")

    return vlog


def decor2(schet):

    global unwrapped
    unwrapped = schet

    def vlog2(a,b):
        print(a+b)
        print("выполняем 2 декоратор")
        schet("mi","la")

    return vlog2


@decor
@decor2
def schet(a,b):

    print (a+b)
    return a+b

c=schet("sa","sha")

# Исходная функция в своём первозданном виде сохранена под именем "unwrapped"
print(unwrapped("sa","sha"))
```

Но, как я уже написал, это извращение, и потребует от вас следить за тем, какой из декораторов у вас самый внутренний, и если порядок применения декораторов поменяется, то нужно будет переносить эти две строчки с сохранением функции в другой декоратор.

Если уж вы ожидаете, что функция вам понадобится в оригинальном виде, не заворачивайте её в декораторы сразу при объявлении, а сделайте это позже под другим именем:

```
def origin(args):
    pass

wrapped = decor2(decor(origin))
```

В этом коде оригинальная функция будет доступна под именем `origin`, а декорированный вариант - под именем `wrapped`.